# Meaning of "wrong word" in Tiger Pro program

Tags: microsoft-word

When analyzing requirement text, that was written by the user, Tiger Pro assumps some words to be "wrong word". What are the rules to determine if a word is "wrong word" or not?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is any word you care to define. So if there is jargon or a word you don't want to be seen outside the company or group, define it as a wrong word and the Tiger will find it.